# How to quickly startup/shutdown Oracle 11?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, centos, startup, shutdown

I am wondering what is the quickest way to properly startup/shutdown a Oracle DB daemon (Oracle 11.2, installed on a test machine).

I need it for C/C++ programs that use the OCI/Pro*C API.

I want this because I am used to the startup speed of PostgreSQL, and because the daemon runs in a virtual machine which is only started (on-demand) for test cases.

Currently I script it like this - startup:

```
sqlplus /nolog <<EOF
connect / as sysdba
startup
quit
EOF
lsnrctl start
emctl start dbconsole
```

And shutdown:

```
emctl stop dbconsole
lsnrctl stop
sqlplus /nolog <<EOF
connect / as sysdba
shutdown
quit
EOF
```

This works - programs work as expected - but this procedure is quite slow.

The Oracle DB runs on CentOS 6.3, it is the free (as-in-beer) available 'standard version'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `dbstart`/`dbshut` scripts which come with an Oracle install. They are available under `$ORACLE_HOME/bin`.

After a fresh install you have to edit the `/etc/oratab` file:

```
# cat /etc/oratab
# format: $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:N|Y
my_sid:/home/juser/app/juser/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:N
# sed -i 's/:N$/:Y/' /etc/oratab
# grep my_sid /etc/oratab
my_sid:/home/juser/app/juser/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1:Y
```

Then you can use the scripts like this:

```
$ whoami
juser
$ dbstart $ORACLE_HOME
$ # execute DB jobs ...
$ dbshut $ORACLE_HOME
```

`dbstart` brings all up which is needed for Pro*C/OCI programs.

Using `dbstart`/`dbshut` is an improvement above the custom method mentioned in the question:

```
method                time    called tools
―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
dbstart              5.7 s    lsnrctl, sqlplus
dbshut               5.7 s    lsnrctl, sqlplus
custom startup      27.9 s    lsnrctl, sqlplus, emctl
custom shutdown     31.0 s    lsnrctl, sqlplus, emctl
```

(times on a Core i7/2.8GHz system, slow spinning hard disk.)

### How dbstart/dbshut work

A `dbstart $ORACLE_HOME$` call is basically equivalent to:

```
$ lsnrctl start
$ echo -e 'connect / as sysdba\nstartup\nquit'| sqlplus /nolog
```

And a `dbshut $ORACLE_HOME$` is basically equivalent to:

```
$ lsnrctl stop
$ echo -e 'connect / as sysdba\nshutdown\nquit'| sqlplus /nolog
```

(you can verify if everything is shutdown via `ps aux | grep 'tnsl\|ora'`)

Note that the order of the commands is important. That means when `lsnrctl start` is executed after the sqlplus-startup command then the Pro*C/OCI program still complains about an unavailable TNS-listener.

And this is exactly the problem with the command sequence in the question - where the `emctl start` just workarounds the wrong order because it fixes the TNS-listener setup part.

Also note that for executing Pro*C/OCI programs the EMCTL service is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need it at all? What is the reason? For shutdown you have 3 options:

- plain `shutdown` - waits for sessions end
- `shutdown immediate` - rollbacks and ends sessions (waits for rollback finish)
- `shutdown abort` - kills everything - usually database has to perform some recovery on startup.

PS: you probably do not need Enterprise manager to run, if you need the database for tests only. Use the Oracle `dbstart`/`dbshut` scripts. If you really need EM, start it in the background.

Answer (score 0):

*[yasir-arsanukaev](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/119/yasir-arsanukaev)*: Can you just pause (suspend) your VM saving its state to disk?

*[colin-t-hart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10361/colin-t-hart)*: If this is a test machine, create a snapshot. Start the machine and start Oracle using `dbstart`. Just force off the machine when done and rollback to the snapshot.